# Mapbox Map not showing on android

Tags: java, android-studio, mapbox

When I tested it the first couple of times it was showing perfectly well, then I added some code and it just stopped. It still shows the Mapbox logo on the left bottom screen but it's not loading the map. Here's the code on the `MapActivity`:

```java
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener {

    private MapView mapView;
    private Button startButton;

    private MapboxMap map;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private Location originLocation;
    private LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin;
    private Locash customerLocash;
    private Point destinationPosition;
    private Point originPosition;
    private Marker destinationMarker;
    private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);


        startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        Intent activityIntent = getIntent();
        String locationJson = activityIntent.getStringExtra("location");

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        customerLocash = gson.fromJson(locationJson,Locash.class);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Launch Navigation
                NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                        .origin(originPosition)
                        .destination(destinationPosition)
                        .shouldSimulateRoute(true)
                        .build();
                NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MapActivity.this, options);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map = mapboxMap;
        enableLocation();

        LatLng point = new LatLng(customerLocash.getLongitude(),customerLocash.getLatitude());

        destinationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));

        destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(),point.getLatitude());
        originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originLocation.getLongitude(), originLocation.getLatitude());
        getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);

        startButton.setEnabled(true);

    }

    private void enableLocation() {
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)){ 
            initializeLocationEngine();
            initializeLocationLayer();
            
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void initializeLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this)
                .obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.activate();

        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
        if (lastLocation != null){
            originLocation = lastLocation;
            setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
        } else {
            locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void initializeLocationLayer() {
        locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine);
        locationLayerPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
        locationLayerPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        locationLayerPlugin.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);

    }

    private void setCameraPosition(Location location){
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude()),13.0));
    }

    private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination){
        NavigationRoute.builder()
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        if (response.body()  == null){
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "No Routes Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        } else if (response.body().routes().size() == 0){
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "No Routes Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        DirectionsRoute currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                        navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView,map);
                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Error:" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null){
            originLocation = location;
            setCameraPosition(location);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted){
            enableLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (locationEngine != null){
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationLayerPlugin != null){
            locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
        }
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (locationEngine != null){
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationLayerPlugin != null){
            locationLayerPlugin.onStop();
        }
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState, @NonNull PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (locationEngine != null){
            locationEngine.deactivate();
        }
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Oh and the Locash object is a class I use to store user location on firebase and the likes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem I had. Not sure if this is the same, but in my case setting the `textureView` option to `true` solved it.

This is how I did it in code:

```kotlin
val resourceOptions = ResourceOptions.Builder()
            .accessToken(context.getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
            .build()

mapView = MapView(context, MapInitOptions(context, resourceOptions).apply { textureView = true })
```

I am not sure how to do it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in XML

<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView

...

app:mapbox_renderTextureMode="true"/>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).