# Flutter MapBox map display/layout issue on Android

Tags: android, flutter, layout, navigation, mapbox

I am new to Flutter and trying to integrate a MapBox map with Turn by Turn navigation in an iOS and Android app.

I am using the [flutter_mapbox_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation) package and [MapBoxNavigationView](https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/blob/master/lib/src/embedded/view.dart).

- iOS: Works as expected
  [image: screenshot iOS simulator]
- Android API 30: the mapbox logo seems to indicate that the widget is at the right place but the map itself is off

[image: screenshot android emulator API 30]

- Android API 27, 28 and 29: The map seems to show correctly, but the MapBox logo is not visible, which to me indicates that something is still off
  [image: screenshot android emulator API 29]
- Android API 26: map and MapBox logo visible at the right location
  [image: screenshot android emulator API 26]
- Android API 24 and 25: MapBox logo at the right position but map is not visible at all
  [image: screenshot android emulator API 24]

I have tried different ways of sizing and positionning the widget but the issue remains.

I have tried using Flutter widget inspector but everything seems fine as far as I can tell.
I have tried using Android Studio Layout but I see a blank page.

I have found this thread but there is no solution [Mapbox Map not showing on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282914/mapbox-map-not-showing-on-android)

I am on macOS Monterey 12.3.1 (Apple M1)

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mapbox_navigation/library.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _options = MapBoxOptions();
  Future<void> _onRouteEvent(e) async {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Column(
        children: [
          const Text("test"),
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 200,
              child: MapBoxNavigationView(
                options: _options,
                onRouteEvent: _onRouteEvent,
                onCreated: (MapBoxNavigationViewController controller) async {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yml

```yaml
name: poc
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_mapbox_navigation: ^0.0.26

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sometimes the mapbox doesn't go well with the Android Emulator. Have you tried deploy onto a real device?

Comment: Are you sure that it should work on such old versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

I removed the [flutter_mapbox_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation) package and reimplemented Android integration by hand using a `PlatformView`. At first I still had the same issue, but then I found about the `textureView` option and this solved my problem.

```kotlin
val resourceOptions = ResourceOptions.Builder()
            .accessToken(context.getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
            .build()

mapView = MapView(context, MapInitOptions(context, resourceOptions).apply { textureView = true })
```